# How to download j connector using terminal?

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way I can download J connector for MySql directly using terminal ? 
I am asking this because I am working on amazon server. And all I can do is connect to that server using putty which gives me a terminal. Please suggest If there are better ways.

Comment: Check ifyou have ftp access?

Comment: i dont know how to check

Comment: I am such a junk and am still able to do things based on documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To download MySQL Connector/J:
Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
Click the blue "Download" button
Right-click on "No thanks blah blah.." and copy link address
In the shell type the following

```
$ wget "Link Address should be pasted here"
```

decompress the index.html file using

```
$ tar -zxvf index.html
```

you get your j connector right inside the newly created folder

Answer (score 1):

To download MySQL Connector/J:

1. Log into dev.mysql.com using Oracle SSO
2. Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
3. Right-click the blue "Download" button and choose "Copy Link Address" (or something similar)
4. Paste the URL in your Terminal

Depending on what you got available, you could use wget or curl to download. With curl you would use the -l options with the -o option specifying a filename:

```
 shell> curl -L -o mysql-connector-java.tar.gz http://...
 or
 shell> wget http://...
```

Comment: It doesnt work for this particular case. The result of download is a file called index.html. i dont know what to do with that. It is supposed to be a .tar.gz file which i can decompress

Comment: I'm always logged in (since I worked huh), so I was missing a step in my answer. Also, note the -l and -o options for curl.